# Why is this error being shown while importing a module?

Tags: typescript, faker

I have a bug, what can i do? I'm still a beginner in Typescript , I wanted to try importing and exporting in typescript but it doesn't look like it

```
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: Expected ',', got 'Esuperio'

  /media/abdulvoris/66C0DC25C0DBF8EF/Abdulvoris/app/maps/node_modules/faker/lib/locales/it/name/first_name.js:396:11
    395 |   'Eros',
  > 396 |   'Esa�',
  >     |          ^
    397 |   'Esuperio',
    398 |   'Eterie',
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by

```
import faker from 'faker/dist/faker.js'
```

for now.

Answer (score 0):

That strange character on line 396, which looks like a diamond containing a question mark, is a "replacement character" indicating that the system is unable to "render a stream of data to a correct symbol". I'm not sure what the name is supposed to be, but I have the same problem as you, and I just went into the node module itself (by option-clicking the filename) and changed the replacement character to an "l" (any normal ASCII character should work fine).

Usually you shouldn't mess around in node modules, but it will fix the problem and allow Parcel to build the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this issue. https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/issues/1247
Due to the non-utf8 chars, we get build errors with parcel. I saw some forks at the issue that I mentioned.